# Airplay to Mac - Is it possible to remove the "accept/decline" prompt?

Tags: macos, imac, airplay, monterey

I have an iMac with AirPlay receiver set as "Anyone from the same network". Therefore I would like to allow everyone at home (with different apple ids) to airplay on the iMac.

But there is always a prompt to allow or decline an incomming airplay on the iMac. Is there a way to always allow connections? Or to remember the choice for each device?

[image]

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to disable this.  I also saw your post on reddit so I hope one of these gets a good response.  I would be interested in this, also.